# How to use default export with file-loader?

Tags: webpack

In my webpack config I use the file loader configured as follows:

```
 {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: [
                    /(node_modules)/,
                    /index\.html$/
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Now when I try to import an html file like it says in the file-loader documentation

`import template from './xyz.html'`

then template is resolved to `undefined`.

It works when I use

`import * as template from './xyz.html'` but I'd rather use the notation from the documentation. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: what happens when you `import './xyz.html'` ?

Comment: The file gets imported but I have no handle on the generated hash path.

Comment: tried this? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#function

Comment: I am not sure how this helps. I _do_ get the hash when I use the import I stated in my last paragraph. The file-loader documentation just says it should work otherwise.